# C# - Check for attribute's existence on enum's element

Tags: c#, attributes, enums, element, defined

I've got a situation like the following:

```
enum Header
{
    Sync,
    [OldProtocol] Keepalive,
    Ping,
    [OldProtocol] Auth,
    [OldProtocol] LoginData
    //...
}
```

I need to obtain an array of elements on which the `OldProtocolAttribute` is defined. I've noticed that the `Attribute.IsDefined()` method and its overloads apparently don't support this kind of situation.

My question is:

- Is there a way to solve the problem without using in any part of the solution `typeof(Header).GetField()`?
- If not, what's the most optimal way to solve it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you have to get the attribute from the field. You'd use:

```
var field = typeof(Header).GetField(value.ToString());
var old = field.IsDefined(typeof(OldProtocolAttribute), false);
```

Or to get a whole array:

```
var attributeType = typeof(OldProtocolAttribute);
var array = typeof(Header).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                     BindingFlags.Static)
                          .Where(field => field.IsDefined(attributeType, false))
                          .Select(field => (Header) field.GetValue(null))
                          .ToArray();
```

Obviously if you need this often, you may well want to cache the results.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, u miss ")" after ".Where(field => field.IsDefined(attributeType, false)" - this code will not compile.

Comment: Actually it will cache internally.

Comment: @AridaneÁlamo: `IsDefined` may cache, but if the OP needs the whole array of fields frequently, it would be worth caching that.

Answer (score 5):

Reflection is pretty much your only tool available for this. The query is not too bad though:

```
var oldFields = typeof(Header).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Select(field => Attribute.IsDefined(field, typeof(OldProtocolAttribute)));
```